# Trim (leading 0 from field)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a problem with below query.Please advise me to overcome this problem.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)

FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE FIELD = '2'
AND FILED2 = '0B'    
AND TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM FILED3) = TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM '00');
```

`FIELD3` is 4 character size and its saved as `00` in Table. So the condition becomes `null = null` which return `false`.

Is there any alternate to to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use something like the following to avoid null comparison:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE FIELD = '2'
AND FILED2 = '0B'    
AND NVL(TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM FILED3), 'NULL') = NVL(TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM '00'), 'NULL');
```

Basically when there is null, I convert it to string, so the comparison is possible.

This is useful if you are comparing against different values ever time. But if you are comparing against NULL always, then use `IS NULL`

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE FIELD = '2'
AND FILED2 = '0B'    
AND TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM FILED3) IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle treats empty string as `NULL`. Use `IS NULL` to compare:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE FIELD = '2'
AND FILED2 = '0B'    
AND TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM FILED3) IS NULL;
```